# Enable Change-Tracking on Azure VM with terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I am currently working on enabling Change-Tracking on Azure VM using AMA and terraform. But this has not been possible. Unfortunately, I can not find any sample code related to this online either. All contributions are highly welcomed and appreciated. I want to enable it using AMA agent with Terraform rather than Azure portal as shown in the below image. Thank you in advance for your help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znOAK.png)

I have used Azure change-tracking policy and change-tracking extension (not supported by terraform) but none could resolve it

Comment: Have you tried any configuration & faced any blocker? @AdorableTech

Comment: @VinayB Yes, but with ChangeTracking ARM Template using azurerm_virtual_machine_extension and also an extension block inside azurerm_monitor_data_collection_rule resources. I know these are  not the natural ways, but I gave it a try to see if something reasonable will come up. But unfortunately, none is successful eventhough the resources were successfully created by terraform without error

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to enable Enable Change-Tracking on Azure VM with Terraform I was able to achieve the requirement successfully.

Since I was not provided with any terraform configuration info. I tried to create every resource that was necessary for this configuration.

**My terraform configuration:**

```
# provider.tf
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}

# variables.tf
variable "location" {
  description = "Azure region location for resources."
  default     = "East US"
}

variable "resource_group_name" {
  description = "The name of the resource group."
  default     = "demorgvk"
}

variable "workspace_name" {
  description = "The name for the Log Analytics Workspace."
  default     = "sbvk-analytics-workspace"
}

variable "automation_account_name" {
  description = "The name for the Automation Account."
  default     = "sbvk-automation-account"
}

variable "vm_name" {
  description = "The name of the virtual machine."
  default     = "sbvk-vm"
}

variable "admin_username" {
  description = "Admin username for the VM."
  default     = "adminuser"
}

variable "admin_password" {
  description = "Admin password for the VM."
  default     = "Password1234!"
}

# main.tf
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = var.resource_group_name
  location = var.location
}

# Log Analytics Workspace
resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "la_workspace" {
  name                = var.workspace_name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days   = 30
}

# Automation Account
resource "azurerm_automation_account" "automation_account" {
  name                = var.automation_account_name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  sku_name = "Basic"
}


# Virtual Network Configuration
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = "myVnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

# Subnet Configuration
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  name                 = "mySubnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
}

# Create a NIC for the VM
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {
  name                = "myNic"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.subnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}


# VM and related resources
resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  name                = var.vm_name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  size                = "Standard_DS1_v2"
  # Assuming you have your network interface set up and its ID is in the variable nic_id
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.nic.id]

  os_disk {
    name              = "myOSDisk"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Premium_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "0001-com-ubuntu-server-focal"
    sku       = "20_04-lts"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  computer_name  = var.vm_name
  admin_username = var.admin_username
  admin_password = var.admin_password
  disable_password_authentication = false
}

# Change Tracking extension
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "change_tracking" {
  name                 = "changetracking"
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.vm.id
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Azure.Monitoring.DependencyAgent"
  type                 = "DependencyAgentLinux"
  type_handler_version = "9.10"
  settings = "{}"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "change_tracking_oms" {
  name                 = "ChangeTrackingOMS"
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.vm.id
  publisher            = "Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring"
  type                 = "OmsAgentForLinux"
  type_handler_version = "1.13"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
      "workspaceId": "${azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.la_workspace.workspace_id}"
    }
SETTINGS

  protected_settings = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
    {
      "workspaceKey": "${azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.la_workspace.primary_shared_key}"
    }
PROTECTED_SETTINGS
}

# outputs.tf
output "resource_group_name" {
  value = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

output "log_analytics_workspace_id" {
  value = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.la_workspace.workspace_id
}

output "vm_id" {
  value = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.vm.id
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

By looking here we can understand that the change tracking on Azure VM was enabled & by again clicking on configure with AMA we can change/update the log analytics workspace attached. This means the existing one was auto-enabled with one log analytics workspace.

Comment: thank you for the effort you have invested in this. Looking at the code and the results, the CT was created using MMA(Log analytics agent) which is already deprecated and will be removed by 2024.  CT is working smoothly with MMA but my issue is getting it working with AMA ( Azure Monitoring Agent).  Thank you once again and let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: To transition from the Microsoft Monitoring Agent (MMA) to the Azure Monitor Agent (AMA) for Change Tracking, you will need to update your Terraform configuration to use the new agent, the Azure Monitor Agent could be deployed using the azurerm_monitoring_agent resource within Terraform, but it was a relatively new addition, so you would need to ensure you're using a version of the azurerm provider that supports this resource

Comment: Hi, thank you for your feedback. But do you by any chance have a link to this terraform resource? Because I have combed azurerm provider but couldn't find any azurerm_monitoring_agent resource. However, if you are talking about AMA extension, yes, I have used that in the past but still not working. I will be implementing other possible solutions I have in mind this week. I will give you feedback on the outcome. Thank you

Comment: Hi, You mentioned that you couldn't find an azurerm_monitoring_agent resource, which is accurate because such a resource does not exist by that name in the Terraform AzureRM provider. Instead, for monitoring purposes, you should be using the azurerm_virtual_machine_extension resource to apply the OmsAgentForLinux extension to your VM, which I have done correctly in my Terraform configuration. This extension is part of the Azure Monitor tools and is used to connect your VM to a Log Analytics workspace for monitoring.

Comment: Hi, I have tried all that possibilities but none seems working till now. But I am still working on it and hopefully I will soon have a workaround.